# How to unit test onBeforeRendering of SAPUI5 control?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sapui5

Let's assume that I have the following code:

```
var title = new sap.m.Title();
title.addEventDelegate({
    onBeforeRendering: jQuery.proxy(function () {
        title.setText(this._createTitleText());
    }, this)
});
```

which sets the text to the `title` only on before rendering.

The question is ***how to unit test this***?

As I understand SAPUI5 framework will fire this event and then I should be able to attach to it and verify that the text of the title is correct, but how to do it and is it a right way?

This is what I was trying, but at least I don't get any text from my control plus for me it is not clear which data I should pass to this method.

```
title.attachBeforeRendering("data", function (oEvent) {
    var text = title.getText();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following way:

```
title.addEventDelegate({
    onBeforeRendering: jQuery.proxy(function () {
        assert.equal(title.getText(), expectedTitle, "Title has correct text");
    }, this)
});
```

However, this is not enough because `onBeforeRendering` will happen after the test which means that it depends on the time thus it is not sure if it is going to happen. But there is a way to make it for sure:

In the end of the test we should call:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        QUnit.start();
    }, 100);
});
```

which will cover our case plus continue executing to another unit test.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call onAfterRendering manually or just invalidate or rerender the control.

Try to do something like

```
// act
oTitle.onAfterRendering();

// assert
assert.strictEqual(oTitle.getTitle(), "__expected_title__", "Title is correct!");
```

In case you are just testing if the title is changed. I would prefer to stub the setTitle method and check if it is called with a correct parameter.

You can see that usually events are tested in this way e.g.
https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/test/sap/m/qunit/MultiComboBox.qunit.html#L4479

In your case you don't need a fake event, but it is quite similar.